# How to access setAdapter in Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, picasso

I have a following `Fragment` class:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
  ....
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos_tab, container, false);
     TabelAdapter adapt = new TabelAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_room_view, flowerList);
     setListAdapter(adapt);     // Not Working because class is not extended by ListActivity
     return view;
   }
```

## TabelAdapter class

```
public class TabelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> {

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_flower_view, parent, false);
    }
    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg")
            .fit()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);
    return convertView;
}
```

## list_flower_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Flowerimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

## activity_home.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I was working with `activity` instead of `fragment` then the whole process was very simple. I extend `MainActivity` class with `ListActivity` and add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` into `MainActivity.OnCreate()`. I can see the list of Images in `ListView`.

## Question

How to make `setListAdapter` usable in `Fragment` class? I am newbie in `Android`. Any help will be appreciable :)

## Edit-1

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment photo = new TabFragment();
            return photo;  // Line (30,24)
  }        ......
 }
```

If I use `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment` then `PagerAdapter` class os throwing an Error.

```
Error:(30, 24) error: incompatible types: TabFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

## Edit-2

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: @dieter_h It's a compile error. Just pasted it

Comment: Incompatible types. There are 2 different types of Fragments, Check imports. `import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;` and  `import android.app.ListFragment` [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)                   [two](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Fragment` to `ListFragment`:

```
 public class TabFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TabelAdapter adapt = new TabelAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_room_view, flowerList);
        setListAdapter(adapt);
       }
     ...
    }
```

[ListFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity)

Comment: What will happen to `activity_home? because in `Activity` class I need to use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)`

Comment: Only  fragment will be change.

Comment: can you please look at Edit-1 section

Comment: My first question : see Edit-2 section. `activity_home` has `list_view` and the fragment is not using it. While I was using `Activity` I had to pass this `list_view` in contect

Comment: Great! What about `onCreateView` in TabFragment class?

Comment: Delete it. It is no longer necessary because you use `ListFragment`.

Comment: Getting Same Error! by logically it should be because I am not linking any `ListView` to `Fragment` class